# All Access Pass: Can't Download Included Products

Tags: wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

I'm having issues setting up the All Access Pass with Easy Digital Downloads. Whenever a user tries to download a products that is included in their All Access Pass it gives the following notice:

> You must have an active subscription to XXXXX in order to download
> this file.

However, the relevant Download variant included in their All Access Pass is shown as having no price and the download button. Products and variants outside of their All Access Pass show a price and the checkout button.

So, it appears that EDD is detecting these product variants as being a part of their All Access Pass. So why can't they download their included Download product?

If a Download products is purchased outside of the All Access Pass, it can be downloaded without issue. But, not when the item is a part of an All Access Pass. It suggests that the Download product subscription isn't being overridden by the All Access Pass in terms of the downloading part.

Here's how the products & passes are setup:

I have Recurring Payments extension installed and have all Download products on a year subscription. I also have All Access extension installed and created a pass which grants access to variant 1 of all Download products. The All Access Passes are also on a yearly subscription.

P.s. I'm trying to set this up for a client who no longer has an active license for the All Access extension so we are unable to currently go via the dev support for this.

Comment: This question is off-topic.  Any question about software tools commonly used by programmers, must be **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this options:

Downloads > Tools > General. And select: All Access - Process All Access Passes.

Go to Downloads > Customers. In this section you can select 1 customer an go to: Customer Details > Tools. And Try with this option: Regenerate Customer All Access Passes.